# Use of wasn't vs was not in a formal sentence

Tags: contractions

In the following sentence :

```
The figure was tall, bespectacled, although in spite of the opacity of the glasses it wasn’t immediately clear whether or not he truly was blind.
```

I am told the use of "wasn't" is insufficiently formal enough in comparison to the rest of the sentence, and that I should use "was not" instead.

Would the sentence be shocking/uncomfortable to native-readers?

Comment: That use of "wasn't" sounds fine to me. What sounds a bit questionable is the idea that one could tell whether a person is blind just by looking at them. Also, "bespectacled" doesn't prompt one to think of sunglasses, so the subsequent mention of opacity immediately forces the reader to revise the mental picture that was forming. Not sure I'd talk about "opacity" of glasses either, given sunglasses are not opaque to the wearer.

Comment: A better answer would be forthcoming if you could provide the next part of the sentence; what was it that the opacity of the glasses "was not". Give us a little help here. Thank you.